# Time Complexity Difference between Two Parsing Implementations Using Global Variables and Return Values

Tags: parsing, time-complexity

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

A string containing only lower-case letters can be encoded into `NUM[encoded string]` format. For example, `aaa` can be encoded into `3[a]`. Given an encoded string, find its original string according to the following grammar.

```
S -> {E}
E -> NUM[S] | STR  # NUM[S] means encoded, while STR means not.
NUM -> 1 | 2 | ... | 9
STR -> {LETTER}
LETTER -> a | b | ... | z
```

Note: in the above grammar `{}` represents "concatenate 0 or more times".

For example, given the encoded string `3[a2[c]]`, the result (original string) is `accaccacc`.

I think this can be parsed by recursive descent parsing, and there are two ways to implement it:

- Method I: Let the parsing method to return the result string directly.
- Method II: Use a global variable, and each parsing method can just append characters to it.

I'm wondering if the two methods share the same time complexity. Suppose the result string is of length `t`. Then for `method II`, I think its time complexity should be `O(t)` because we read and write every character in the result string exactly once. For `method I`, however, my intuition was that it could be slower because the same substring can be copied multiple times, depending on the depth of recursions. But I'm not able to figure out the exact time complexity to justify my intuition. Can anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion is that your parser should produce an abstract syntax tree rather than directly interpret the string, no matter whether you choose to write a recursive descent parser, a state-based parser or use a parser generator. This greatly enhances maintainability and allows you perform validation, analyses, and transformations much more easily.

#### Method I

If I understand you correctly, in Method I you have functions for each grammar construct that return an immutable string, which are then recursively repeated and concatenated. For example, for the top-level concatenation rule

```
S ::= E*
```

you would have an interpretation function that looks like this:

```
string interpretS(NodeS sNode) {
    string result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < sNode.Expressions.Length; i++) {
        result = result + interpretE(sNode.Expressions[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

... and similarly for the other rules. It is easy to see that the time complexity of Method I is `O(n²)` where `n` is the length of the output. (*NB: It makes sense to measure the time complexity in terms of the output rather than the input, since the output length is exponential in the length of the input, and so any interpretation method must have time complexity at least exponential in the input, which is not very interesting.*) For example, interpreting the input `abcdef` requires concatenating `a` and `b`, then concatenating the result with `c`, then concatenating that result with `d` etc., resulting in 1+2+3+4+5 steps. (See [here](https://ericlippert.com/2013/06/24/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-two/) for a more detailed discussion why repeated string concatenation with immutable strings has quadratic complexity.)

#### Method II

I interpret your description of Method II like this: instead of returning individual strings which have to be combined, you keep a reference to a mutable structure representing a string that supports appending. This could be a data structure like `StringBuilder` in Java or .NET, or just a dynamic-length list of characters. The important bit is that appending a string of length `b` to a string of length `a` can be done in `O(b)` (rather than `O(a+b)`).

Note that for this to work, you don't need a *global* variable! A cleaner solution would just pass the reference to the resulting structure through (this pattern is called *accumulator parameter*). So now we would have functions like these:

```
void interpretS2(NodeS sNode, StringBuilder accumulator) {
   for (int i = 0; i < sNode.Expressions.Length; i++) {
      interpretE2(sNode.Expressions[i], accumulator);
   }
}

void interpretE2(NodeE eNode, StringBuilder accumulator) {
   if (eNode is NodeNum numNode) {
       for (int i = 0; i < numNode.Repetitions; i++) {
          interpretS2(numNode.Expression, accumulator);
       }
   }
   else if (eNode is NodeStr strNode) {
      for (int i = 0; i < strNode.Letters.Length; i++) {
         interpretLetter2(strNode.Letters[i], accumulator);
      }
   }
}

void interpretLetter2(NodeLetter letterNode, StringBuilder accumulator) {
    accumulator.Append(letterNode.Letter);
}
...
```

As you stated correctly, here the time complexity is `O(n)`, since at each step exactly one character of the output is appended to the accumulator, and no strings are ever copied (only at the very end, when the mutable structure is converted into the output string).

So, at least for this grammar, Method II is clearly preferable.

---

#### Update based on comment

Of course, my interpretation of Method I above is exceedingly naive. A more realistic implementation of the `interpretS` function would internally use a `StringBuilder` to concatenate the results from the subexpressions, resulting in linear complexity for the example given above, `abcdef`.

However, this wouldn't change the worst case complexity `O(n²)`: consider the example

```
1[a1[b[1[c[1[d[1[e[1[f]]]]]]]]]]
```

Even the less naive version of Method I would first append `f` to `e` (1 step), then append `ef` to `d` (+ 2 steps), then append `def` to `c` (+ 3 steps) and so on, amounting to 1+2+3+4+5 steps in total.

The fundamental reason for the quadratic time complexity of Method I is that the results from the subexpressions are copied to create the new subresult to be returned.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I just have one question regarding the code section in `method I`. If in that section we change the type of the variable `result`  from `string` to `StringBuilder`, will the time complexity still be O(n^2)? I feel that for a specific function call of `interpretS`, each character returned by `interpretE` is copied exactly once, so it takes O(n) time per function invocation right? How to get the total time complexity O(n^2) for `method I` in this case? Thanks again!

Comment: @Patrick I updated my answer accordingly. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Time Complexity is estimated by counting the number of elementary operations performed by an algorithm, supposing that each elementary operation takes a fixed amount of time to perform, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity). Of interest is, however, only how fast this number of operations increases, when the size of the input data set increases.
In your case, the size of the input data means the length of the string to be parsed.

I assume by your 1st method you mean that when a NUM is encountered, its argument is processed by the parser completely NUM times. In your example, when „3“ is read from the input string, „a2[c]“ is processed completely 3 times. Processing here means to transverse the syntax tree up to a leave, and append the leave value, here the „c“ to the output string.

I also assume by your 2nd method you mean that when a NUM is encountered, its argument is only evaluated once and all intermediate results are stored and re-used. In your example, when „3“ is read from the input string and stored, „a“ is read from the input string and stored, „2[c]“ is processed, i.e. „2“ is read from the input string and stored, and finally „c“ is processed. „c“ is due to the stored „2“ combined to „cc“, and due to the stored „a“ combined to „acc“. This is due to the stored „3“ combined then to „accaccacc“, and „accaccacc“ is output.

The question now is, what is the elementary operation that is relevant to the time complexity? My feeling is that in the 1st case, the stack operations during transversal of the syntax tree are important, while in the 2nd case, string copying operations are important.
Strictly speaking, one can thus not compare the time complexities of both algorithms.
If you are, however, interested in run times instead of time complexities, my guess is that the stack operations take more time than string copying, and that then method 2 is preferable.

Comment: Thanks! I think for method I, we don't need to process the same string multiple times right? For example, for `3[a2[c]]`, we just need to call the parse method on `a2[c]` once and store the intermediate result. Then copy this string three times. Did I misunderstand anything?

Comment: You are right;  I think this is the faster method.